# removing max in each turn and pop medium element and make max sum

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, heap

**two friends X and Y decided to play a game .they have an even length array of elements N. Each time X picks any number from array which is
not yet taken and Y picks median of remaining elements (median means middle index element e.g {10 20 500} here median means middle element i.e floor of len(array)/2 == 1. Element present at index 1 ...I.E 20 in this case)  . The game continues for (N/2) turns for each player.
Your task is to find maximum sum that X can get at the end of game.**

**Input Format:**
first line contains N:

- 2<=N<=400000
- N is even

the next line contains pair N integers:

- 0<=A[i]<=10^9

**Output Format:**
output a single integer - the max sum X can get at the end.

**Sample Testcase #0**

**testcase input:**
4
1 2 3 4

**output:**
7

**Explaination:**
X chooses 4 and array becomes {1,2,3}

the element at median position is 2, so Y gets 2

X chooses 3 and array becomes {1}

the element at median position is 1, so Y gets 1.

So,total sum X has is (4+3) = 7 which is maximum possible.

**Sample testcase #1**

**input:**
4
5 10 15 5

**output:**
20

I tried Brute Force method but getting TLE for all cases.
any efficient algorithm for this??

Comment: Why 20 for 5 10 15 5 set?

Comment: @MBo median refers to the position in the array, not to the value!

Comment: @Damien OK, thanks,  it was not clear from the problem statement

Comment: I strongly suggest editing the question, because "the element in middle position in the array" and "the median" are not synonymous.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.